# Linux USB: Where to report that a specific device is in fact supported by `usbserial`, although not recognised automatically?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb-device, phone

I have an USB device that the kernel does not automatically recognise as an USB serial device but when I manually say to the `usbserial` driver that it should bind to it (`modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0421 product=0x069a`), it provides to USB serial interfaces where useful things can be done over it.

What is the right place (email-address, bug tracker, …) to report it to the correct Linux subsystem maintainers to include that device for automatic binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The kernel documentation for the generic USB serial driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/usb-serial.html#generic-serial-driver) suggests contacting its maintainer, Greg Kroah-Hartman, directly. See the linked file for the email address to use.

However, loading the `usbserial` driver produces a log message indicating what should be done:

> The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
> Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.

So you should send an email to that address with your device ids and a description.

(Interested readers may want to know that this was done both [by email](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20220208125958.295e8a0b@gmx.de/) and [in the kernel bug tracker](http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215579), and led to [a patch](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20220228084919.10656-1-johan@kernel.org/) which was merged in 5.18.)